# Making a layer appear and disappear multiple times in temporal controller

Tags: qgis, point, spatio-temporal-data, temporal-controller

I am making an animation with temporal controller and have a simple point layer that should only be present on certain nonconsecutive days. Previously, I was manually replacing the frames after exporting the animation. Is there a way to select multiple start and stop times so that it appears and reappears multiple times?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use "duplicates" of your layer. choose duplicate in the layers context menu and set different time slots to the duplicates:

[image]

[image]